# .NET regex with quote and space

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to create a regex to match this:

```
/tags/ud617/?sort=active&amp;page=2" >2
```

So basically, "[number]" is the only dynamic part:

```
/tags/ud617/?sort=active&amp;page=[number]" >[number]
```

The closest I've been able to get (in PowerShell) is:

```
[regex]::matches('/tags/ud617/?sort=active&amp;page=2" >2
','/tags/ud617/\?sort=active&amp;page=[0-9]+')
```

But this doesn't provide me with a full match of the dynamic string.

Ultimately, I'll be creating a capture group:

```
/tags/ud617/?sort=active&amp;page=([number])
```

Comment: What regexes have you tried?

Comment: I'm lost when it comes to the quote and greater than.  It doesn't seem like a simple escape will do, so it must be something more complicated to match these like maybe even the ASCII character?

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue. `"` and `>` are not special characters in regexes or in (single-quoted) string literals, so you shouldn't need to escape them at all.

Comment: For crying out loud, I swear I tried it and it didn't work...  Now it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems easy enough:

```
 $regex = '/tags/ud617/\?sort=active&amp;page=(\d+)"\s>2'

'/tags/ud617/?sort=active&amp;page=2" >2' -match $regex > $nul

$matches[1]

2
```

Comment: Thanks.  I must have screwed something up when I was testing because I thought I had tried that except for using "\s" for a space.

Comment: If you're not sure what to escape, you can run the string through [regex]::escape() and see where it puts the backslashes.

Comment: I don't know much about .NET . But in Perl it's possible to set an option so that spaces in a regex are ignored unless they're backslash-escaped. Perhaps this option is on by default?

Comment: I've seen that referred to as "Freespacing mode".  In a dotnet regex it can be enabled using the (?x) option, but the default is disabled.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html

Answer (score 1):

```
[regex]::matches('/tags/ud617/?sort=active&amp;page=3000 >2','/tags/ud617/\?sort=active&amp;page=(\d+) >(\d+)')
```

Outputs:

```
Groups   : {/tags/ud617/?sort=active&amp;page=3000 >2, 3000, 2}
Success  : True
Captures : {/tags/ud617/?sort=active&amp;page=3000 >2}
Index    : 0
Length   : 41
Value    : /tags/ud617/?sort=active&amp;page=3000 >2
```

This captures the `page` value and the number after the greater than i.e. `2`